# Simple ajax post call in Play framework

Tags: java, ajax, playframework, playframework-2.2

Hi I'm trying to simply send a string once a button is pressed in my website using ajax to my java code in Play framework. I can't find a simple tutorial which simply explains how to do this. They are all using templates.
Lets say my java method is:

```
  public static Result upload() { }
```

and my button is calling a javascript method which gets a String from another input when clicked:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="send();">
```

Answer (score 7):

I didn't test, but something like this should work.

**Application controller**

```
public static Result upload() {
    JsonNode node = request().body().asJson().get("stringField");
    String inputString = node.getTextValue();"
    System.out.println(inputString)      // prints the string from the form field
    return ok();
}
```

**Routes**

```
POST        /uploadfoostring       controllers.Application.upload()
```

**Template**

```
<input type="text" id="string-field">

<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="send();">

<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $('#submit').click(function(evt) {
      var inputString = $('#string-field').val();

      var obj = {
        stringField: inputString;
      };

      $.ajax({
        url: "@routes.Application.upload()",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(res) {
          if (res) {
            console.log("Success!");
          } else {
            console.log("Failed...");
          }
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Diego, yes, thanks. I switched the name half way through. I made the edit.

Comment: I'm getting Nullpointer exception on this line `JsonNode node = request().body().asJson().get("stringField");`

Comment: also i want to send my input file aswell. currently my Form has an action to /upload which sends the multipart. is that the reason that ajax is not wroking?

Answer (score 2):

```
POST        /home/testPost                               controllers.Application.testPost

//Server Side.
def testPost = Action { request =>

    println("testPost Called");
    println(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("name").head);
    Ok("Succeeded");

}


Client Side:

public static testPost(){
$.ajax({
url:"/dialog/testPost",
type:"POST",
data:{
name:"Varadharajan R"
},
success:function(response){
alert(response);
}
});
}
```